# @google-cloud/translate causes React web app to have a blank screen in Safari

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, syntax-error, google-translate

I'm making a messaging app that features in-app message translation: https://booker-m.github.io/parley. I'm coding in JavaScript and CSS using the ReactJS library. It works fine on Windows and Android with the Google Translate API imported, but shows a blank white screen in web browsers on iOS.

The moment I include
`const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;`
in my code, it stops loading in Safari and I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
> (anonymous function)  @   2.e2886061.chunk.js:2

I can't find anything about incompatibility issues with the Google Cloud Translate API and Safari and I have no idea why including it would stop my web app from loading.

My question was closed last time but I don't have any extra details- I'm extremely confused why the line:
`const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;`
causes a blank screen on iOS web browsers. I have tried everything I can to fix it, but the issue doesn't seem to be with any of my code aside from importing the Google Cloud Translate API. If I comment that line out, the app will load on my phone when testing with "npm start." If I uncomment that line and save the file, the document's screen goes blank.

You can see the specific code here: https://github.com/Booker-M/parley/blob/master/src/Config/MyTranslate.js

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Can you use `const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');` instead and let me know if it works for you? Taken from the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/nodejs).

Comment: @milia Hi milia, my app stops rendering on Safari the moment I import any version of Google Cloud Translation, including without the .v2 and also with the .v3 or beta.